# Is it possible to use an argument's value in a default argument value assignment in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to use the left-side argument's value in the below function inside of the default argument value to the right.

```
def function(var, vartwo = var*2):
    return vartwo


print(function(7)) #should print 14
print(function(7,6)) #should print 6
```

However I am getting NameError: name 'var' is not defined. Is it not possible use an argument's value in a default argument value in Python? How would you suggest I tackle this problem?

Comment: well, you need to pass the actual 'default' which cannot be the previously declared name of another argument. 
def function(var, vartwo = 'blabla'):
    return vartwo
should work

Comment: another thing - if you need the second argument to be always as the first - ui don't think you need the second argument at all, def function(var):
vartwo = var return vartwo is the same here. or if you explain why do you need the second argument so bad, because it's not clear from this context

Comment: I edited the problem to better explain the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible; how about this?

```
def function(var, vartwo = None):
    if vartwo is None:
        vartwo = var*2
    return vartwo

print(function(7))
print(function(7,6))
```

The hack is to set the default value to `None`, then set it internally. If not none, then return whatever was entered by the user.

Comment: Well this solves his current problem while it's original question remains .. dunno, unanswered - is it possible to pass previously declared argument as default to the next - by var name. python says no (as expected). but how to tackle this in general :D

Comment: Yeah this would work, was kinda hoping not to hack though. I'll take it as a no to being able to use argument values in default. I'll just set as answer.

Comment: uhm... as far as i know, `var` has to be defined to be used.

Comment: however this satisfies his requirement, so +1

Comment: Thanks @MiroRodozov!  :)

Answer (score 2):

Pass the buck:

```
def function(var, *args):
    return (lambda var, vartwo=var * 2: vartwo)(var, *args)


print(function(7))  # should print 14
print(function(7, 6))  # should print 6
```

> I know about lambda functions but mind adding explanation?

Since we can't use `var` in `vartwo`'s definition, we delay by setting up a new argument list, via a `lambda`, where `var` is now defined and the default for `vartwo` is legal.

I've made this somewhat confusing by reusing the `var` variable name to represent two different variables (a formal parameter to `function` and a formal parameter to `lambda`) and also act as a positional place holder.

I could, and probably should, have written this more simply as:

```
def function(var, *args):
    return (lambda vartwo=var * 2: vartwo)(*args)
```

But I wanted to retain the flavor of the original problem.

Comment: Nice, very pythonic

Comment: I know about lambda functions but mind adding explanation?

Comment: @JoelAntonioDelacruzParedes, I've added a bit of explanation as well as a simplfication.  Let me know if it's insufficient.

Comment: Is this solution the faster than a vartwo = None hack?

Comment: @JoelAntonioDelacruzParedes, this seems an odd place to look for speed, but I'd say "no", mine is slower, despite it doing its conditional test at the C level, as the the overhead of the extra function call (lambda) dominates.  So expect it to be ~ 1/2 as fast.  (We may be talking as little as ~ 1/2 a microsecond per call.)

Answer (score 0):

What your doing won't work because var hasn't been declared. Here's a different approach:

```
def function(var, multiply=False):
    if multiply:
        return var * 2
    else:
        return var

print(function(7, True))  # 14
print(function(6))  # 6
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use a value that is not defined outside of the function as a argument value for that function.

For an alternative, I'm late to the party, but how about something short and simple that will work if `None` is the second parameter?

```
def function(var, *args):
    return args[0] if args else var * 2


print(function(7))  # prints 14
print(function(7, 6))  # prints 6
print(function(7, None))  # prints 'None'
```

Here, `args` is the list of arguments provided after `var`, and could be an empty list. We then return the first element of this list if the list is not empty (which is equivalent to the second argument). If the list is empty, we return `var * 2`.

The caveat here is that this will not throw the appropriate error if more than two arguments are provided. You can choose to manually raise a `TypeError` if `len(args) > 1` (remembering that `args` are parameters *after* the first one) if this is important to enforce.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the value of another argument in default value. The reason is very simple: the default values are evaluated exactly once: at the time when the function definition was executed.

One common pattern to use is to have the second argument be set to a special sentinel value by default, then test if the argument was set again within the function:

```
SENTINEL = object()

def function(var, vartwo=SENTINEL):
    # was vartwo set?
    if vartwo is not SENTINEL:
        return vartwo

    return var * 2
```

This way the function would return `vartwo` correctly even when you'd pass in `None` or any other value for it, unless you specifically passed the `SENTINEL` constant.